Detect heart rate in WEAR OS Emulator in Android Studio
How to Detect heart rate in WEAR OS Emulator in Android Studio
The code I am trying does not give errors, but I cannot see the heart rate in the emulator.
I am using wearos3 and Android API 30
Is it possible to detect heart rate in emulators or not?
I am using synthetic exercise commands
adb shell am broadcast \ -a "whs.synthetic.user.START_RUNNING" \ com.google.android.wearable.healthservices
Broadcasting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x400000 pkg= -a }
Broadcast completed

Can you please share suggestions?
Detect heart rate in emulator in android studio

Yes, according to this Simulate sensor data with Health Services:

If you're testing on an emulator running Wear OS 3, you can also use synthetic data to test your app.

Have you followed the steps described in Enable synthetic data generation?

Enable developer options.

1. Open the watch's Settings.
2. Tap System > About > Versions.
3. Tap the Build number item seven times.
4. A message appears confirming that you are now a developer.


Issue the following adb command to enable synthetic mode:

adb shell am broadcast \
-a "whs.USE_SYNTHETIC_PROVIDERS" \
com.google.android.wearable.healthservices


I guess it's also depending what API is being used to retrieve HEART_RATE data. If Health Services are being used then yes synthetic data might work, but if the HEART_RATE data is coming from the Android Sensors API, I doubt synthetic data will simulate that latter one.

Thank you for your feedback. I used adb shell command to enable synthetic mode but could not see heart rate even after broadcast got completed. I was not able to see any changes in heart rate even after I changed it on the emulator panel. Can you suggest how can I see changes in heart rate. Thank you

Thank you for your suggestions I am able to detect heart rate throught the panel now I will incorporate health services to see if I can simulate it through adb command.
